# How to convert boxed two dimensional string to 2 dimensional integer array and viceversa in c#

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have String which have a 2 dimensional array i need to convert these 2D string to integer array.
 example:

```
String temp ="[[0xFF008041, 0x24008086, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,0x0008383A]]".
```

I need the 2D string value to 2d Integer array and viceversa

Comment: Well in this case you've only got a single "inner" array - will it always be like that, or might it sometimes be `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`? It sounds like basically you need to do string manipulation. I'd initially split the outer array into strings which are the inner arrays, then parse each of those separately.

Comment: Is this json you are trying to parse? What have you tried?

Comment: Looks like JSON to me... Possibly using JSON parser and than creating 2d array would work - but hard to see what exactly you have problem with.

Comment: how to convert string like "[[2,3],[4,5],[3,4]]" to two dimensional integer array.

Comment: While I agree this question can and should be asked better, I don't believe it's too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String temp = "[[0xFF008041, 0x24008086, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,0x0008383A]]";
            temp = temp.Replace("[", "");
            temp = temp.Replace("]", "");
            string[] tempArray = temp.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            uint[] tempIntArray = tempArray.Select(x => FromHex(x)).ToArray();
        }
        static uint FromHex(string value)
        {
            uint results;
            uint.TryParse(value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out results);
            return results;
        }​
```

Comment: Can't use Linq in .net 2.0... read the tags of the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since it's `.Net 2.0` you can't use the benefits of more modern versions such as `Linq`, I would suggest using `Split`, `for` loops, `Trim`, and `Convert`:

**Note #1:** I'm working under the assumption that the numbers in the string will always be hex numbers.

**Note #2:** I'm returning a jagged array and not a multidimensional array, since you can't enforce all the inner arrays in the string to have the same number of elements.

```
String temp = "[[0xFF008041, 0x24008086, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,0x0008383A], [0x0008, 0x0034B]]";

int[][] ConvertStringToJaggedArray(String input)
{
    String[] Separator = { "],[", "], [", "] ,[" };
    String[] OuterArray = input.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int[][] TargetArray = new int[OuterArray.Length][];
    string HexString;
    for (int i = 0; i < OuterArray.Length; i++)
    {
        String[] InnerArray = OuterArray[i].Split(',');
        TargetArray[i] = new int[InnerArray.Length];
        for (int j = 0; j < InnerArray.Length; j++ )
        {
            HexString = InnerArray[j].Trim(" []".ToCharArray());
            TargetArray[i][j] = Convert.ToInt32(HexString, 16);
        }
    }
    return TargetArray;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question?